# How can I move liquibase block from build.gradle to standalone plugin on java?

Tags: java, gradle, liquibase, gradle-plugin

I faced with issue that I need use Liquibase migration without running application. (through the command `./gradlew update`)
I added the following section to one of my projects:

```
if (!project.hasProperty("url")) {
    project.ext.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
}
if (!project.hasProperty("username")) {
    project.ext.username = "test"
}
if (!project.hasProperty("password")) {
    project.ext.password = "test"
}
if (!project.hasProperty("defaultSchemaName")) {
    project.ext.defaultSchemaName = "test"
}
if (!project.hasProperty("changelogFile")) {
    project.ext.changelogFile = "some-path/changelog-master.xml"
}

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            driver "org.postgresql.Driver"
            url project.ext.url
            username project.ext.username
            password project.ext.password
            defaultSchemaName project.ext.defaultSchemaName
            changelogFile project.ext.changelogFile
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but it takes up a lot of space in `build.gradle`, and the same task needs to be added to other projects as well.

Is it possible to bring this section into a plugin and organize work through the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that helped me:

```
    private void configureExtension(Project project) {
    project.getExtensions().configure(LiquibaseExtension.class, liquibaseExtension -> {
        var activity = liquibaseExtension.getActivities().create("main");
        var arguments = new HashMap<>() {
            {
                put("url", url);
                put("username", username);
                put("password", password);
                put("defaultSchemaName", defaultSchemaName);
                put("classpath", classpath);
                put("changeLogFile", changeLogFile);
            }
        };
        activity.setArguments(arguments);
        liquibaseExtension.getActivities().add(activity);
    });
}
```